# What x86 32 bit peepholes does GCC perform?

Tags: gcc, x86, compiler-optimization

I've been browsing through the GCC source code and I've been stumped on how to extract these. Can anyone provide a list or information on how to extract these peepholes (assembly rewrite optimizations)?

GCC code: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc

**Edit**: To clarify, a "peephole" is defined to be a find and replace pattern with some associated side conditions for the rewrite to be valid (often just some register/flags liveness information).

Comment: related: LLVM version of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286761/what-x86-32-bit-peepholes-does-llvm-perform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the various `*.md` files and search for `define_peephole`.

For example: `gcc/config/i386/i386.md` contains (among many others):

```
;; For HI, SI and DI modes, or $-1,reg is smaller than mov $-1,reg.
(define_peephole2
  [(set (match_operand:SWI248 0 "register_operand")
    (const_int -1))]
  "(optimize_insn_for_size_p () || TARGET_MOVE_M1_VIA_OR)
   && GENERAL_REGNO_P (REGNO (operands[0]))
   && peep2_regno_dead_p (0, FLAGS_REG)"
  [(parallel [(set (match_dup 0) (const_int -1))
          (clobber (reg:CC FLAGS_REG))])]
{
  if (<MODE_SIZE> < GET_MODE_SIZE (SImode))
    operands[0] = gen_lowpart (SImode, operands[0]);
})
```

The relevant documentation is in the GCC Internals Manual

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Peephole-Definitions.html#Peephole-Definitions

Answer (score 2):

It is really off-topic since too broad here.

You might look into my [documentation](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) page of [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/); it has several useful references (notably the [Indian GCC resource center](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/)), and most of the slides I wrote contain reference and tutorial material...

Most of GCC optimizations happen in the (target & source neutral) middle-end layers, not in the backend.

And [peephole optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization) does not means much (precisely) these days, and most of the optimization power of GCC does not come from it.

Comment: I don't see how this is too broad, in fact it seems like an incredibly specific request.

Comment: @Daryl: it's too broad because there are boatloads of things, like recognizing a pair of matching shifts ORed together as a rotate, replacing a div by a constant with a multiply, etc. etc.  Although many of those are cross-platform and happen in the middle end.  IDK what would be peephole.  Maybe replacing a shift+add with LEA on x86?

Comment: > "IDK what would be peephole"
A find and replace pattern with some side conditions? Maybe I've underestimated how messy GCC's code for this is. I was hoping there was some way to just extract a list of ~30-100 such patterns.