# Does a file with whitespaces and newlines compile slower than one without?

Tags: compilation, compiler-optimization

Let me state something. I **don't** need the performance but I was wondering if a file like this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){printf("Hello, world!");}
```

gets compiled faster than this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(vod)
{
    printf("Hello, world!");
}
```

because the compiler doesn't have to skip as much newlines and whitespaces as in the other text.

Comment: That's a resounding **no**

Comment: No. But I'm old enough to remember when people tried it, and also to save disk space.  Back in 1979 I worked on a COBOL program for NCR which had all spaces and newlines removed. Complete nightmare.

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you: [Wikipedia: Compiler Contruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Compiler_construction)

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to measure the difference.  However, if you start each line with a thousand spaces, it will take (a very little) longer to process than a file without so many spaces, simply because the file size is smaller.  The performance difference will be extremely hard to measure because a compiler does so much else as well.

Comment: Have you tried measuring the difference?

Comment: Text parsing is a very tiny fraction of the total time, especially for modern optimizing compilers.  Even with optimization disabled it's trivial.  See [Disable all optimization options in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33284629) / [Why are there so few C compilers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/273698)